# Google maps - custom marker with number

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently displaying a marker using the following code:

```
var marker = new google.maps,Marker({
  map: maps,
  position: coordinate,
  icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+ (position) +'|FF776B|000000',
});
```

This displays the default map marker with a number.

Question is, can you have a custom icon, lets say `marker.png` then have a number overlayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify your marker like this:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

var styleMaker1 = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:"00ff00",text:"1"}),position:myLatLng,map:map});
```

Comment: I know how to do that. What I want, is a custom marker, that has a number overlayed. My code displays the default marker with the number.

Comment: check out the google styled markers custom library http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look to see if that helps. I'm using a function that is a php loop to add markers.

Comment: then read this document first https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Comment: In my view this is not a correct answer. The question was about combining a custom marker image and an arbitrary number string.

Answer (score 1):

Use **markerWithLabel.js** library...

Here is the code:

```
marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            map: maps,
            position: coordinate,
            icon : yourMarkerImage,
            labelContent : yourNumberOnMarker,
            labelAnchor : yourLabelPosition,     // e.g. new google.maps.Point(21, 10);
            labelClass : "labels",          // the CSS class for the label
            labelInBackground : false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been into this, and used the Google Charts API, but if you want a custom marker based on a png for example you can go via PHP and image libraries to return you custom marker based on your parameters, similar as how the Google Charts API you are calling.